# How to rclone copy only .png files under a directory?

Tags: rclone

I have lots of files under dir1/ in the server.
I want to copy all the png files under dir1/*.png to google drive.

However

```
rclone copy dir1/*.png gdrive:dir2/
```

gives error.

```
Usage:
  rclone copy source:path dest:path [flags]

Flags:
      --create-empty-src-dirs   Create empty source dirs on destination after copy
  -h, --help                    help for copy

Use "rclone [command] --help" for more information about a command.
Use "rclone help flags" for to see the global flags.
Use "rclone help backends" for a list of supported services.
Command copy needs 2 arguments maximum: you provided 66 non flag arguments:
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

"perfect" with `--include` :-)

```
rclone copy dir1/ gdrive:dir2/ --include "*.png"
```

Comment: I will try it and revisit here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found a way to resolve this issue in another way around.

I used the `--exclude` flag.

In this way, I exclude the `directory_I_do_not_want_to_copy_under_dir1` and all of its contents.

Therefore I copied the remaining under `dir1/` including `*.png` files.

Not perfect but an approximate solution :)

```
rclone copy dir1/ gdrive:dir2/ --exclude==/directory_I_do_not_want_to_copy_under_dir1/**
```